# Search data based on user input

Tags: datatable, search

I have a datatable which is populated by a JSON object, what I want to do is this: when the user types a letter I want to display all the values that have that letter, but I still don't know how to do this, I can read the value inputed by the user through console.log, but I don't know how to compare the value the user is typing and display it. Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<lightning-card  title="THE MEAL DB API" icon-name="custom:custom63">
  <lightning-input type="search" onchange={handleSearch}>
  </lightning-input>
  <lightning-button label="Search meal" variant="brand" onclick={handleMealName}>
  </lightning-button>

      <lightning-datatable key-field="id" 
                            data={mealNames} 
                            columns={columns} 
                            sorted-by={sortBy}
                            sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                            onsort={handleSort}
                            hide-checkbox-column="true"
                            default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}>
      </lightning-datatable>

      <template if:true={mealSearched}> 
        <lightning-datatable key-field="Id"
                             data={mealSearched}
                             columns={columns}
        ></lightning-datatable>
      </template>

      <template if:false={mealSpinner} class="slds-spinner_inline spinner-padding">
        <lightning-spinner variant="brand"
                           alternative-text="Loading"
                           size="large">
        </lightning-spinner>
      </template>
</lightning-card>
```

JS:

```
import { api, track, wire, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getMealData from '@salesforce/apex/MealsRetriever.getMealData';

const columns =[
    {label: 'Meal ID', fieldName: 'idMeal', editable: false, sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true},
    {label: 'Meal', fieldName: 'strMeal', editable: false, sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true},
    {label: 'Category', fieldName: 'strCategory', editable: false, sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true},
    {label: 'Meal Origin', fieldName: 'strArea', editable: false, sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true},
    {label: 'How to prepare', fieldName: 'strInstructions', editable: false, sortable: true},
];

export default class DataTableWithSortingInLWC extends LightningElement {
    
    @track columns = columns;
    @track sortBy;
    @track sortDirection;
    @track mealNames;
    @track mealSpinner = false;
    @track searchKey;
    @track mealSearched;

    @wire(getMealData)
        mealDataResult(result){
            const {data, error} = result;
            if(data){
                this.mealNames = data;
                this.mealSpinner = true;
                this.error = undefined;
            } else if(error){
                this.mealNames = undefined;
                this.error = error;
            }
        }
    
    handleSearch(event){
        this.mealSearched = event.target.value;
        console.log('User typed:', this.mealSearched);
    }

    handleMealName(){
        getMealData(
            {searchKey: '$mealSearched'}
        )
        .then(result =>{
            this.searchKey = result;
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            this.searchKey = undefined;
            this.error = error;
        })
    }

    handleSort(event){
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        this.sortData(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
    }

    sortData(fieldname, direction) {
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mealNames));
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; 
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });
        this.mealNames = parseData;
    }  
}
```

APEX:

```
public with sharing class MealsRetriever {
    private static final String MEAL_URL = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=';
    private static final String GET = 'GET';
  
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<MealData.Meal> getMealData(String searchKey){
        String key = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        Http httpCallout = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(MEAL_URL);
        req.setMethod(GET);
        HttpResponse resp = httpCallout.send(req);

        MealData mealResponse = (MealData) JSON.deserialize(resp.getBody(), MealData.class);
        List<MealData.Meal> mealData = new List<MealData.Meal>();
        
        for(MealData.Meal m: mealResponse.meals){
            mealData.add(m);
        }

        return mealData;
    }
     
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to have the remote system filter based on the URL parameter of your endpoint, or filter in either Apex or JavaScript? You've got most of the pieces you need here, but it's not consistent.

Comment: Since the values are already being displayed to the user I would like to render and display the searched value in the table, so I'd like to filter with JS only, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For Client Side Fitlering***

It's not clear against what you are comparing your query string, however, if you plan on searching for a string within a property of an array of Objects, you can refer to [How TO - Filter/Search List](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp)

The approach used in the post is obviously not the best for your use case, however, it does layout the basics of comparing a string against a value.

you could use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get Objects from your array that match a certain condition as follows:

```
querySearchResults(queryString) {
    this.objectsThatMatch= this.allTheObjectsArray.filter(
        item=> item.[PROPERTY].toUpperCase().indexOf(queryString) > -1)
```

`this.objectsThatMatch` would be the property that you would need to pass to your table that has matching values from the query.

Additionally, you might want to [remove all the `@track` decorators](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_track.htm&type=5&release=224), they are not necessary.

Furthermore, depending on the amount of objects in your table, you might want to use "[setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)" to delay your query.

Comment: Hello glls, thanks for taking your time to answer me. You said my approach is not the best for this case, can you which one would be the most appropriate? I'm a begginer in programming yet

Comment: I meant, the post I shared, because it "hides" and "displays" values based on the query string, whilst here we "filter" values based on the string to return a new array of iterable objects for your table.

Comment: Looking at the post from the W3Schools, that was what I wanted my table to display and hide the values, but is that a bad pratice?

Comment: it's easier to manage a subset of results using filter for you to display in your page than to apply hide/display to individual results based on a query string